# DependencyProperty propery not called in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, binding

I previously posted a problem based on the same problem but I thought I'd start again with more accurate information as there were too many factors I thought were at the source of the problem which weren't actually relevant.

I have a `UserControl` in a windows phone app in which I need to add a property that will be bound to a property declared in my `ViewModel`. From what I've read on the net and I understood, I need to create a `DependencyProperty` in order to make it bindable.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceFileProperty = DependencyProperty.
Register("SourceFile", typeof(string), typeof(ViewerControl), 
new PropertyMetadata(""));

public string SourceFile
{
    get
    {
         return base.GetValue(SourceFileProperty) as string;
    }
    set
    {
         base.SetValue(SourceFileProperty, value);
    }
}
```

This is the property in my `ViewModel`:

```
public string DocumentUri
{
    get { return this._documentUri; }
    set
    {
        if (this._documentUri != value)
        {
            this.SetProperty(ref this._documentUri, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `SetProperty` takes take of the `INotifyPropertyChange` and my `ViewModel` is definitely bound as other properties are used and are updating correctly but these are not bound to my user control.

This is my XAML

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <cc:ViewerControl SourceFile="{Binding DocumentUri}" />
    </StackPanel>                        
</Grid>
```

I've got a breakpoint on the getter and setter of my `DocumentUri` in my `ViewModel` and the `SourceFile` in the `UserControl` and on the definition of the `DependencyProperty`.

When I run my code, the `DocumentUri` is called accordingly, the definition of the `DependencyProperty` is also initialized but it never calls the getter/setter of the `SourceFile` property in my `UserControl`.

NOTE: If I define the property as a regular CLR property, I get an error which makes no sense:

> Value does not fall within the expected range

I need the `SourceFile` property to be "triggered" when the `DocumentUri` property is changed.

What I am doing wrong or missing???

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need a dependency property unless you're trying to do animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency property *getter and setter never gets called when DP is get/set from XAML*. That;s why you shouldn't put any code in there.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) link:

> The current WPF implementation of its XAML processor is inherently
>   dependency property aware. The **WPF XAML processor uses property system
>   methods for dependency properties when loading binary XAML and
>   processing attributes that are dependency properties. This effectively
>   bypasses the property wrappers.** When you implement custom dependency
>   properties, you must account for this behavior and should avoid
>   placing any other code in your property wrapper other than the
>   property system methods GetValue and SetValue.

You can use [**PropertyChangedCallback**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to track DP property changes which gets called whenever DP property changes from XAML or from code.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I was about to update my thread when I saw you provided the answer! I found this article which clarified it for me "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42203/How-to-Implement-a-DependencyProperty"

Comment: While it worked, it breaks my xaml preview and displays the following exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Should I handle something else for nullability??

Comment: No it shouldn't. Try rebuilding the solution.

Comment: Hi, I fixed it by adding this check: if (ViewControl != null && e.NewValue != null) {ViewControl.SourceFile = e.NewValue.ToString();}. Thanks.